# facing issues in executing cronjob

Tags: javascript, cron, hosting

Sorry for change in the question.

I have hostgator hosting. In cpanel I have created a cronjob but its not running.

Command: php /home/username/public_html/dir1/dir2/cron.php.
In email now I am getting whole code as it is written in the file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
var i = 0;
    function getdata(){
        var dt = new Date();
         var user1="h";
          var pass= "h";
          var location1='2';
          var passdata = '';
          if(i==0){
            month = '' + (dt.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + (dt.getDate() + 1),
            year = dt.getFullYear();        
            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;        
            var date1 = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;         
            passdata =  "username="+user1+"&password="+pass+"&location="+location1+"&date="+date1;          
          }else{
            var dd=dt.getDate();
            dt.setDate(dd+i);
            month = '' + (dt.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + (dt.getDate()),
            year = dt.getFullYear();                         
            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;                     
            var date2 = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
            //alert(date2);
            passdata =  "username="+user1+"&password="+pass+"&location="+location1+"&date="+date2;  
          }       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "www.site.com",
            data : passdata,
            success: function (data) {
                var new_data=JSON.stringify(data);
                if(i==0){
                    php_send(new_data,date1,2);
                }else{
                    php_send(new_data,date2,2); 
                }

            }
        });
    }
    function php_send(agl,agl1,agl2)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var url="test_php.php";                 
        xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("p="+agl+"&date1="+agl1+"&location="+agl2);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                if(xmlhttp.responseText == 1){
                    i++;
                    if(i<=30){
                        getdata();  
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
     }
    function createCORSRequest(method, url) 
    {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                    
      if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
      } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
      } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
      }
      return xhr;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getdata();"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output when you tried running the same command through terminal? Is that working?

Comment: All of sudden the cronjob starts working but in email I am getting whole code of file.

Comment: In which directory you tried running the file manually? There may be some require statements which may be using some relative path which can cause the execution to proceed.  Can you try the same by changing the directory to /home folder. And check whether you are getting email. ie switch /home folder and try running the file.

Comment: If I try to run it manually it works perfectly.

Comment: running PHP files as a cron job on command line only processes the PHP not the javascript! javascript is client side and as there's no client it wont run.  rewrite your script to have no html or javascript and be all php based and it'll work fine.  it currently works when you run it manually via your web browser as thats processing the javascript.

Comment: Can you specify the cron statement like this and tell the output reading the test.txt file

php /home/username/public_html/dir1/dir2/cron.php > /home/test.txt

Comment: Sanjay Kumar : I am getting the raw code in email as shown in question.

Comment: Sanjay Kumar: Can you sugegst me other options pls.

Answer (score 0):

try /usr/bin/php-cli /home/username/public_html/dir1/dir2/cron.php
or 
php -q /home/username/public_html/dir1/dir2/cron.php